# Application Insights Monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I am trying to set up Application Insights on an ASP.NET MVC Web Application and I am not certain on the setup required.

I have added the `Application Insights Telemetry SDK for Services` NuGet package to my project in Visual Studio 2012.

Can someone confirm if I need both the JavaScript in my HTML:

[image: JS]

**AND** the following code in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
    ServerAnalytics.BeginRequest();
    ServerAnalytics.CurrentRequest.LogEvent(
        Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
}
```

I currently have both added to the project and I am getting some usage information, but it is not accurate (0 unique users for example).

I was also getting performance data, but this is no longer happening.

I have been using the links below for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481094.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495324.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn518124.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481098.aspx

Comment: have you tried using the Application Insights Extensions. It may be able to automate the process for you. After installing, right click on your web project and select Add Application Insights Telemetry to Project. [http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/82367b81-3f97-4de1-bbf1-eaf52ddc635a](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/82367b81-3f97-4de1-bbf1-eaf52ddc635a)

Comment: @svarcoe Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm using VS2012 and I think this extension only works for VS2013 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it depends on your tasks. 
Use only Javascript code snippet if you need to log event on Client side but use ServerAnalytics.CurrentRequest.LogEvent() if you want to write event on Server side.

Comment: yes, this is correct.  The different pieces send different kinds of data.  The javascript sends client usage info (what browser, what language, etc) and the server analytics stuff can send information about what's happening on individual servers, how long requests took, what exceptions occurred on the back end, etc.